# Deduce array dimension from array name through C++ template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I remember that ten years ago, there was a piece of code using c++ template meta programming which can deduce the array dimensions from an array name.

For example

```
int a[2][3][4][5][6];
cout << DimOfArray(a) << endl
```

Output:

```
5
```

But I forget the details of that code. I remember it uses `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` tricks. Does anyone know how to write it?

Comment: `a` is a multidimensional array, which dimension should `DimOfArray` return?

Comment: Try [`std::rank` (or `std::rank_v`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank).

Comment: Sorry, it should be 5. I will modify my question.

Answer (score 6):

The original code might have built what today is provided by [std::rank](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank), see section "Possible implementation"; for not having to inherit from integral constant (that wouldn't have existed in those days), it could be modified to:

```
template<typename T>
struct rank { static size_t const value = 0U; };

template<typename T>
struct rank<T[]> { static size_t const value = rank<T>::value + 1; };

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct rank<T[N]> { static size_t const value = rank<T>::value + 1; };
```

The code then would have used this template class in the template function (the template class *might* have been local classes in the function as well):

```
template <typename T>
size_t dimOfArray(T const& array)
{
    return /*std::*/rank<T>::value;
}
```

With modern C++ best declare this function `constexpr`. If you are rather after getting the size of one specific dimension, you could use this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t dimOfArray(T const (&array)[N]) constexpr
{
    return N;
}
```

Again, today you might want to have it `constexpr` (as shown).

The latter (size of a specific dimension) is what you could achieve with `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)` "tricks" as well (instead of the much simpler returning of `N`), I don't see, though, how you'd want to get the number of dimensions with.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11 you have [std::rank](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank), so this little wrapper will do what you want:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
size_t DimOfArray(T const& array) constexpr
{
    return std::rank<T>::value;
}
```